# Why is this person killed in the season finale of Homeland's season 5?

Tags: plot-explanation, homeland

In [A False Glimmer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_False_Glimmer), the season finale of Homeland's Season 5:

> Saul has Allison killed.

Putting aside the trope'ish nature of this execution (the CIA would never do this in real life), why is this course of action chosen?

> Wouldn't it have been better to catch Allison, with the amount of evidence now against her, and have her instead locked up in prison for the rest of her life?

I would have thought that this would be a much more satisfying option for Saul, given the person would have to then deal with the consequences of their actions rather than taking the easy way out.

I saw the episode awhile ago, but this has been bothering me ever since!

Comment: "the CIA would never do this in real life" -- there's no suggestion that this was an official operation authorized by the CIA. Instead it is made to look very much like a clandestine operation conducted by Saul and two other guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Saul was tying up loose ends, both personally and professionally.**

I think you're right that it was a bit over the top to have her killed (especially since we've seen the super-max prison in past seasons, and Allison would likely have provided useful intelligence on the Russians), but Saul appears to have covered everything up, with a vengeance.

This review from Uproxx - [Seven Questions We Have After The Season Finale Of ‘Homeland’](http://uproxx.com/tv/homeland-season-five-finale-questions/3/) - puts it quite well [my emphasis]:

> Why did Saul kill Allison?
>   And why does he look so great in a skull cap? I digress. In particularly badass fashion, Saul and Co. apprehended Allison and her massive Russian drivers in the middle of a dark forest. But rather than take them into the station for questioning, they shot them approximately one million times. **It’s possible that Saul was doing damage control for the CIA — as several characters have mentioned before, Allison’s exposure as a double agent would be a huge PR and logistical nightmare for the agency. But it’s also possible that Saul had something of a personal agenda. Allison made a fool of him on a sexual level, an emotional level, and a professional level. Even Saul’s not above seeking revenge.** (Also: We never found out what happened between Saul and Mira, which might be helpful in figuring out why Saul acted like such a moron all season with Allison. Will we ever find out?)